# OS X Eclipse switch workspace takes two clicks

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have a weird problem on my MacBook Air. When I want to switch workspace in Eclipse and go File->Switch Workspace and choose one of the recent ones. My first click seldom "takes" so have to repeat the procedure twice for the switch to occur.
This is especially true if I have been doing som work in the workspace. If I just open one and immediately switch, it usually works fine.

Is anybody else experiencing this and/or know if there is something to do about it?

[Edit]

Having played around a little it seems to be when I have Eclipse in full screen mode.

I'm on OS X 10.8.2 using Eclipse 4.2.1

Comment: Sounds awkward. I tried some, however, it always works well.

Comment: Would you mind trying in fullscreen mode? I get the same behavior on my Imac when I run Eclipse in fullscreen mode.

Comment: I tried it in full screen mode, the same behavior happens in my MacBook Air.

Comment: Ok, so I guess its an Eclipse bug. I'll see if I can file it with them. Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with the IBM RAD 8.5.1 version of Eclipse.    
The comments above are almost two years old.  Was this issue ever addressed?

Comment: @javawebapps I never resolved it no. Please let me know if you do.